# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with Type_WP_Days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I Did some simple steps in my database

Step 1:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TempType] AS TABLE([MM] [INT])
```

Step 2:

```
CREATE PROC [DBO].[TEMP1] (@MYTAB TEMPTYPE READONLY)  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @MYTAB
END
```

Step 3:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP11 ([MM] [INT])

INSERT INTO #TEMP11 
   SELECT 1 UNION 
   SELECT 2 UNION 
   SELECT 3 

SELECT * FROM #TEMP11

EXEC TEMP1 #TEMP11
```

Result:

```
(4 row(s) affected) 
(4 row(s) affected)
```

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure temp1, Line 0
>   Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with TempType

I did it on two more servers it gave same message. What is the fault in my code. I used SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2014 also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating a temporary table, create a variable of type `TempType`:

```
DECLARE  @Temp11 TempType 

INSERT INTO @Temp11 SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 
SELECT * FROM @Temp11

EXEC TEMP1  @Temp11
```

Your procedure is not accepting a `temporary` table as input parameter but parameter of type `TempType`.